# make causing segmentation fault in android source build

Tags: android, build, makefile

I set up the environment carefully just like mentioned in the Initialising the build environment. Then this.. repo init -u android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b gingerbread
repo sync
source build/envsetup.sh lunch .All these steps run perfectly. –

I get a error like this

```
 lunch 1

 Segmentation fault

 ** Don't have a product spec for: 'full'

** Do you have the right repo manifest?
```

Then I debug this envsetup.sh script I realize that make in the file is causing the segmentation fault . Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN the Initializing a Build EnvironmentGNU , I was supposed to use Make 3.81 -- 3.82, which you can download from gnu.org, Ended up getting another version which resulted in a lot of trouble with the Android source build.